# Spark web framework can not load static files

Tags: java, html, freemarker, spark-java

This implementation of the spark framework get method.

```
 Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");
 get("/job/:jobid", (request, response) -> {
      String jobid = request.params(":jobid");
      JobDAO dao = new JobDAO();
      Job job = dao.getByJobid(jobid);
      Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();
      attributes.put("subTitle", "JOB Detail Information");
      attributes.put("job", job);
      return new ModelAndView(attributes, "job_detail.ftl");
    }, new FreeMarkerEngine());
```

In view i used freemarker to set a href：

```
<a href="job/${jts[s2]}">
```

The variable `${jts[s2]}` is `jobid` that could be `request.params` of previous code snippet.

Now, all static files(css, js files etc) of this URL could not be loaded. This information is shown in chrome console.

```
 http://X.X.X.X::4567/job/js/jquery.min.js
```

The correct response is **http://X.X.X.X:4567/js/jquery.min.js**. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you call `Spark.staticFileLocation("/public");` _before_ calling any other Spark method ?

Comment: @JonasCz  I had used this way，but still don't work.

Comment: I have the problem. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem related to including static files(css, js files etc) in each page but with a layout you just include it once for all pages.
for more information : https://github.com/kwon37xi/freemarker-template-inheritance